# Issue with blob url on mobile devices - committed_interstitials_enabled

Tags: javascript, blob, capture

I'm generating a blob from photo/video taken on a mobile phone browser. I am using the capture html way, with this code:

`<input type="file" id="mediacapture" name="mediacapture" accept="image/*" capture="user"/>`

I then generate a url from the ouput here:

```
let input= document.getElementById('mediacapture');
                input.addEventListener('change', (ev)=>{
                    console.dir( input.files[0] );
                    if(input.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") > -1 ){ //For a type of image
                        console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]));
                        document.getElementById('linkToMediaCapture').href = window.URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
                    }


                })
```

The href link to media capture works fine when used on a desktop browser. I click it and see my blob media no problem. But when I use it with mobile, it runs into an error.

On mobile, it generates the blob no issue. However, when I click the link to view, it shows me an error on all mobile browsers. Errors on Chrome are "The site can't be reached, ERR_FAILED", and on Safari "WebKitBlobResource error 1".

And when I inspected the error, here is the response I received in Chrome:

```
ERROR: Unexpected condition on blob:myurl : could not find value for committed_interstititals_enabled
ERROR: Unexpected condition on blob:myurl : [undefined] (committed_interstititals_enabled) is not a boolean
```

I've googled everywhere and found no similar questions. Researching the error got me this [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/bd9ca31194ec20fdd4faa80518aa4c01a6ca4d89/chrome/browser/ssl/ssl_browsertest.cc), and it looks like something like SSL? But I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. It seems the file is being corrupted somehow on the input itself. I managed to test it by adding some manual scripts to the console:

```
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')]

function testFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()´
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  reader.onloadend = function (e) { if (e.target.result) console.log("Success parsing file", file) }
  reader.onerror = function (e) { console.log('Error parsing file', e) }
}

function register() {
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      const file = e.target.files(0)
      console.log('[onChange] Testing file:', file)
      testFile(file)
    })
  })
}

function readFile(index) {
  const file = elements[index].files[0]
  console.log('[Manual] Testing file:', file)
  testFile(file)
}

// Listen to file inputs changes
register()

// To check an input manually run
// readFile(index) - index refers to the index in the querySelectorAll array
```

I did this because I couldn't run the project locally (company very restrict VPN) and I had to test on a live environment (which sucks), but it works verifying files integrity.

So I could notice that:

- When we attach the file to the input, the files looks fine
- After a small amount of time, the file seems to be corrupted somehow triggering the `WebkitBlobResource error 1`
- The issue happens intermitently, hard to know when it will happen or not... making it hard to debug

I also dont have a solution yet for this and I'm considering that it is a Webkit issue for IOS (happens on safari and chrome, and chrome is basically a modified safari on IOS so same webkit which makes sense). But I'm trying to contribute with some more information here in order to help finding a solution for this.

**Edit with possible fix (2020/10/15):**

I made some research and it seems your case might be related to the target="_blank/_self", try both and see if it fixes your issue.

My issue was related to sending a file on a FormData. In my case I had to convert the file to base64 (so we don't lost any data) on change then when submitting transform the base64 into a file again and send to the FormData this copy of the original file instead. Below the code:

```
/**
 * For generating the base64 string, then I saved it in a variable to read it 
 * again when submitting. You can put this base64 as an anchor href as well to 
 * access it anywhere.
 */
export function createFileFromBase64({ data, name, type }) {
  const BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,'
  const parts = data.split(BASE64_MARKER)
  const raw = window.atob(parts[1])
  const rawLength = raw.length
  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength)

  for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    set(uInt8Array, i, raw.charCodeAt(i))
  }

  return new File([uInt8Array], name, { type })
}

export function processFile(file) {
  return isIOS() ? createBase64FromFile(file) : file
}

/**
 * For creating a file to be sent in the FormData from the giving base64 string.
 */
export function createFileFromBase64({ data, name, type }) {
  const BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,'
  const parts = data.split(BASE64_MARKER)
  const raw = window.atob(parts[1])
  const rawLength = raw.length
  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength)

  for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    set(uInt8Array, i, raw.charCodeAt(i))
  }

  return new File([uInt8Array], name, { type })
}

export const parseFile = file => {
  return isIOS() ? createFileFromBase64(file) : file
}
```

So this is how I managed to workaround the safari issue.
I hope it helps someone else!